# How to check user input against pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails application I need to check user input against patterns consisting of letters, numbers and a few special characters (like dashes and underscores) and I don't know how to do it.

For example, if the pattern is `LL-NNNN` and the user submits a string `AB-0001`, that would be valid.

If the pattern is `NN-LL` and the user submits `77-ABC`, that would be invalid.

I was thinking about converting each pattern into a regular expression, but since each user can define their own pattern (which means there will be many of them) I am concerned that this might lead to unexpected results.

Can anybody tell me what's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Are patterns user-specific? Each user has their own pattern?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a loop, check if each character from the input string satisfies the corresponding pattern-character.

```
def match?(pattern, input)
  return false if pattern.length != input.length
  pattern.each_char.with_index.all? do |char, i|
    case char
    when 'L' then input[i] =~ /[A-Z]/
    when 'N' then input[i] =~ /[0-9]/
    when '-' then input[i] == '-'
    else raise 'invalid pattern'
    end
  end
end

match?('LL-NNNN', 'AB-1234') #=> true
match?('NN-LL', '77-ABC')    #=> false
match?('NN-LL', '77-99')     #=> false
match?('NN-LL', '77-AB')     #=> true
```

Answer (score 4):

If the pattern is always going to be a combination of `L => Letter`, `N => number`, and `-` you could convert it into a regex with `Regex.new(value)`

The whole thing would look like this for either case

```
def match(pattern, value)
  /\A#{pattern.gsub(/[LN]/, 'L' => '[a-zA-Z]', 'N' => '\d')}\z/.match(value)
end
```

and this for only upper case

```
def match(pattern, value)
  /\A#{pattern.gsub(/[LN]/, 'L' => '[A-Z]', 'N' => '\d')}\z/.match(value)
end
```

You could even do the conversion to regex format early, and store the regex in the DB instead of the pattern to optimize processing time.

```
def regex_from_pattern(pattern)
  "\\A#{pattern.gsub(/[LN]/, 'L' => '[a-zA-Z]', 'N' => '\d')}\\z"
end

def match(regex_string, value)
  Regexp.new(regex_string).match(value)
end
```

Comment: Alternatively `/\A#{pattern.gsub(/[LN]/, 'L' => '[A-Z]', 'N' => '\d')}\z/`

Comment: @Stefan that does look cleaner for the option of runtime conversions.  updating those. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Because we like one-liners so much in Ruby, here's a quick hack.

Replace the input characters with their corresponding pattern-character:

```
'AB-1234'.gsub(/[A-Z]/, 'N') #=> "NN-1234"
         .gsub(/[0-9]/, 'L') #=> "NN-LLLL"
```

And compare the result to the pattern:

```
'AB-1234'.gsub(/[A-Z]/, 'N').gsub(/[0-9]/, 'L') == 'NN-LLLL'
#=> true
```

Comment: I tried to do slightly different with `"AB-0001".tr("A-z", "L").tr("0-9", "N")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create regexp builder and `Regexp.escape` will help you.
Let's assume you've set user defined pattern alphabet:

```
ALPHABET = 'LN-_:=.\\'
```

Then you can check if user's pattern is right:

```
PATTERN_REGEXP = Regexp.new('\A[%s]+\z' % Regexp.escape(ALPHABET))
def is_pattern_ok?(pattern)
  PATTERN_REGEXP =~ pattern
end
```

Next step is to created user defined input regexp string from his pattern:

```
def regexp_str_from(pattern)
  ('\A%s\z' % Regexp.escape(pattern))
    .gsub('N', '\d')
    .gsub('L', '[a-zA-Z]'))
end
```

And save it somewhere in user settings in DB.
So, you can validate user input with user defined pattern:

```
Regexp.new(regexp_str) =~ user_input
```

Edited: Note: `Regexp.escape` is mandatory to avoid "unexpected results".

Comment: `\w` matches word characters which includes letters but also includes numbers and underscores, you need to replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]` or `[A-Z]` in the `regexp_str_from(pattern) function` to fit the pattern described

Answer (score -1):

You can use this in our model

```
validates_format_of :your_field_name, with: /(your regex)/i, on: :create
```

Comment: Okay, but how do you construct `/(your regex)/i` out of `'LL-NNNN'`?

Comment: do you want to create regex depending on what the user input is?

Comment: The pattern is also user-defined: _"each user can define their own pattern"_